# Joomla admin login is not showing any error and is not redirecting to dashboard

Tags: joomla

I have a login problem with Joomla administrator page. When I enter the login credentials it is "**not redirecting to the dashboard**" or it is not showing any error. It simply stays on the same page **after a load** but it is not redirecting.

I tried with the follwing configurations in phpMyAdmin database:
1) **"plg_authentication_joomla"** under jos_extensions have set with the following values to following attributes:
               a)Enabled : 1
               b)Access :1
               c)Protected:1
               d)state:0

2)**plg_authentication_ldap** under jos_extensions have set with the following values:
               a)Enabled : 0
               b)Access :1
               c)Protected:0
               d)state:0
3)**plg_user_joomla** under jos_extensions have set the following values:
               a)Enabled : 1
               b)Access :2
               c)Protected:0
               d)state:0

I have also tried resetting the password under **jos_users**. But not changes...Kindly help me...

Comment: P.S. it helps to report the exact Joomla version

Answer (score 0):

The "plg_user_joomla" normally has "access" set to 1.
Not sure if this will fix your problem but it's definitely something you should correct.